Every Cauchy sequence in $M/N$ converges.
Let $M$ be a filtered module with filtration $(M_k)$ and $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Then the filtration on $M/N$ is given by $(P_k)$ where $P_k=(M_k+N)/N$. We will show that if $M$ is complete and thus every Cauchy sequence in $M$ converges, then every Cauchy sequence in $M/N$ also converges.
Let $(x_n+N)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $M/N$. We will construct a Cauchy sequence $(y_n)$ in $M$ such that $(x_n+N)=(y_n+N)$. Set $x_1=y_1$. Suppose $y_n$ has been chosen such that $y_n+N=x_n+N$. Note that since $(x_n+N)$ is Cauchy for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $x_{n+1}-x_{n}+N\in (M_k+N)/N$ eventually. So $x_{n+1}-x_n+N=p+j+N$ for some $p\in M_k$ and $j\in N$. Thus $x_{n+1}-x_n-p-j\in N$. Then for some $u\in N$ we have $x_{n+1}-x_n+u\in M_k$ eventually. Choose $y_{n+1}=x_{n+1}-(x_n-y_n)+u$. Then $y_{n+1}+N=x_{n+1}+N$ and $y_{n+1}-y_n=x_{n+1}-x_n+u\in M_k$ eventually so $(y_n)$ is Cauchy and since $M$ is complete $(y_n)$ converges to some $y\in M$. Then $\lim (x_n+N)=\lim(y_n+N)=y+N$.
Is this proof correct? I am doubtful about the last sentence and the choice of $u$.
